# Modified Base 64 for URLs, or Custom/Arbitrary "Base" based on custom alphabet, in PHP

Tags: php, math

I've searched around, but after sifting through quite a lot of posts, I haven't really seen this covered --

I'd like to convert an unsigned, base-10 integer to a much higher "custom" base, by providing the "alphabet", but I'm not sure where to start, and am probably overlooking the simplicity.

As [mentioned on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications), there are variants of traditional Base 64 that do not add padding, etc., for use in URLs and what-not, but I am not sure how to begin implementing that. 
8
I'm **not encoding strings or binary data** - just plain integer numbers - and **would like to be able to feed an arbitrarily-long "alphabet" into the conversion function**. Ideally, of course, I would be able to reverse the numbers as well.

I'm using PHP, but I should be able to work with anything using straightforward math and not a lot of custom libraries, of course.

Comment: What is wrong with using base64?

Comment: Padding, and the fact that the built-in PHP `base64_encode()` doesn't work directly on Integers, but turns them into (ASCII?) strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this article, you can find a function to exactly what you ask *(Look at the "Creating a super-compressed URL" section)* :  [**Building a URL Shortener**](http://snook.ca/archives/php/url-shortener)

Basically, that function :

- Encodes an integer,
- Allows you to use whatever *alphabet* you want

And there is a reverse function just below ;-)

Comment: Thanks! And y'know, I'm pretty certain that I read that article when Jonathan posted it. I knew I had this information locked in my brain somewhere!

Comment: I remembered I had bookmarked it *(well, something about that subject)* when it's been posted, actually ; a quick search in my bookmarks, and voila ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I [coded a function to do exactly this for phunction](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/77448cda4ef28aa861ed957f4ce966cac55dbb6c/_.php#L1542), here is the stand-alone version:

```
function Base($number, $input, $output, $charset = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
{
    if (strlen($charset) >= 2)
    {
        $input = max(2, min($input, strlen($charset)));
        $output = max(2, min($output, strlen($charset)));
        $number = ltrim(preg_replace('~[^' . preg_quote(substr($charset, 0, $input), '~') . ']+~', '', $number), $charset[0]);

        if (strlen($number) > 0)
        {
            if ($input != 10)
            {
                $result = 0;

                foreach (str_split(strrev($number)) as $key => $value)
                {
                    $result += pow($input, $key) * intval(strpos($charset, $value));
                }

                $number = $result;
            }

            if ($output != 10)
            {
                $result = $charset[$number % $output];

                while (($number = floor($number / $output)) > 0)
                {
                    $result = $charset[$number % $output] . $result;
                }

                $number = $result;
            }

            return $number;
        }

        return $charset[0];
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
var_dump(Base(1000, 10, 62)); // g8
var_dump(Base('g8', 62, 10)); // 1000

var_dump(Base(14776336, 10, 62)); // 10000
var_dump(Base('10000', 62, 10)); // 14776336
```

By default I'm using a base 62 charset but you can change this to fit your needs.

Comment: damn, it was an accidental down vote. I was actually going to upvote the answer!

Comment: @Leonel: Just so you know, you can switch the vote - just click the up arrow to vote up or click again on the down arrow to remove your vote.

Comment: Actually I can't. It says "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." Sorry :(

Comment: @Leonel: Yeah, you had like 2 hours to retract it. No worries =).